# Creating a new column for long weekend with existing public holiday and weekend columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns date, week_day, public_holiday and weekend.

```
 weekday Date           Public_Holiday? Weekend?
   5     2015-01-10              no      yes
   0     2015-01-12              no       no
   1     2015-01-13              no       no
   2     2015-01-14              no       no
   3     2015-01-15              no       no
   4     2015-01-16              no       no
   5     2015-01-17              no      yes
   6     2015-01-18              no      yes
   0     2015-01-19              no       no
   1     2015-01-20              no       no
   2     2015-01-21              no       no
   3     2015-01-22              no       no
   4     2015-01-23              yes      no
   5     2015-01-24              no      yes
   6     2015-01-25              no      yes
   1     2015-01-27              no       no
   2     2015-01-28              no       no
   3     2015-01-29              no       no
   4     2015-01-30              no       no
   5     2015-01-31              no      yes
   0     2015-02-02              no       no
   1     2015-02-03              no       no
   2     2015-02-04              no       no
   3     2015-02-05              no       no
   4     2015-02-06              no       no
   5     2015-02-07              no      yes
   6     2015-02-08              no      yes
   0     2015-02-09              yes      no
   1     2015-02-10              no       no
   2     2015-02-11              no       no
```

I need to add an additional column which has the long weekend flag. The output should look like the below.

```
    long_weekend  weekday   Date          Public_Holiday? Weekend?
            0        5     2015-01-10              no      yes
            0        0     2015-01-12              no       no
            0        1     2015-01-13              no       no
            0        2     2015-01-14              no       no
            0        3     2015-01-15              no       no
            0        4     2015-01-16              no       no
            0        5     2015-01-17              no      yes
            0        6     2015-01-18              no      yes
            0        0     2015-01-19              no       no
            0        1     2015-01-20              no       no
            0        2     2015-01-21              no       no
            0        3     2015-01-22              no       no
            1        4     2015-01-23              yes      no
            1        5     2015-01-24              no      yes
            1        6     2015-01-25              no      yes
            0        1     2015-01-27              no       no
            0        2     2015-01-28              no       no
            0        3     2015-01-29              no       no
            0        4     2015-01-30              no       no
            0        5     2015-01-31              no      yes
            0        0     2015-02-02              no       no
            0        1     2015-02-03              no       no
            0        2     2015-02-04              no       no
            0        3     2015-02-05              no       no
            0        4     2015-02-06              no       no
            1        5     2015-02-07              no      yes
            1        6     2015-02-08              no      yes
            1        0     2015-02-09              yes      no
            0        1     2015-02-10              no       no
            0        2     2015-02-11              no       no
```

The regular weekends are not considered as long weekends. Only if friday or monday and in some cases if thursdays or tuesdays are holidays, the entire series is considered as longweekend.

Here is what I have tried below

```
df['long_weekend'] = np.where((df['Public_Holiday?'] == 'yes') | (df['Weekend?'] == 'yes'), 1, 0)
df['weekday'] = df['Predicted_Date'].dt.dayofweek
df['long_weekend'] = np.where(((df['long_weekend'] == 1) & (df['weekday'] == 4)) | (df['long_weekend'] == 1) & (df['weekday'] == 0)), 'yes','no')
```

This gives me the following output which even has regular weekdays as 1.

```
    long_weekend  weekday         Date   Public_Holiday? Weekend?
            1        5     2015-01-10              no      yes
            0        0     2015-01-12              no       no
            0        1     2015-01-13              no       no
            0        2     2015-01-14              no       no
            0        3     2015-01-15              no       no
            0        4     2015-01-16              no       no
            1        5     2015-01-17              no      yes
            1        6     2015-01-18              no      yes
            0        0     2015-01-19              no       no
            0        1     2015-01-20              no       no
            0        2     2015-01-21              no       no
            0        3     2015-01-22              no       no
            1        4     2015-01-23              yes      no
            1        5     2015-01-24              no      yes
            1        6     2015-01-25              no      yes
            0        1     2015-01-27              no       no
            0        2     2015-01-28              no       no
            0        3     2015-01-29              no       no
            0        4     2015-01-30              no       no
            1        5     2015-01-31              no      yes
            0        0     2015-02-02              no       no
            0        1     2015-02-03              no       no
            0        2     2015-02-04              no       no
            0        3     2015-02-05              no       no
            0        4     2015-02-06              no       no
            1        5     2015-02-07              no      yes
            1        6     2015-02-08              no      yes
            1        0     2015-02-09              yes      no
            0        1     2015-02-10              no       no
            0        2     2015-02-11              no       no
```

How can I get this working? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your output posted for df['long_weekend'] is in the form - `1 0 1` but in your code you are assigning `yes no` to  df['long_weekend'], can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create consecutive groups by `shift` with `cumsum` and count number of groups with `map` and `value_counts` and filter with more as `2`:

```
long = (df['Public_Holiday?'] == 'yes') | (df['Weekend?'] == 'yes')
s = long.ne(long.shift()).cumsum()
df['long_weekend'] = np.where((s.map(s.value_counts()) > 2) & long, 1, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
    weekday Predicted_Date Public_Holiday? Weekend?  long_weekend
0         5     2015-01-10              no      yes             0
1         0     2015-01-12              no       no             0
2         1     2015-01-13              no       no             0
3         2     2015-01-14              no       no             0
4         3     2015-01-15              no       no             0
5         4     2015-01-16              no       no             0
6         5     2015-01-17              no      yes             0
7         6     2015-01-18              no      yes             0
8         0     2015-01-19              no       no             0
9         1     2015-01-20              no       no             0
10        2     2015-01-21              no       no             0
11        3     2015-01-22              no       no             0
12        4     2015-01-23             yes       no             1
13        5     2015-01-24              no      yes             1
14        6     2015-01-25              no      yes             1
15        1     2015-01-27              no       no             0
16        2     2015-01-28              no       no             0
17        3     2015-01-29              no       no             0
18        4     2015-01-30              no       no             0
19        5     2015-01-31              no      yes             0
20        0     2015-02-02              no       no             0
21        1     2015-02-03              no       no             0
22        2     2015-02-04              no       no             0
23        3     2015-02-05              no       no             0
24        4     2015-02-06              no       no             0
25        5     2015-02-07              no      yes             1
26        6     2015-02-08              no      yes             1
27        0     2015-02-09             yes       no             1
28        1     2015-02-10              no       no             0
29        2     2015-02-11              no       no             0
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @jezraer's very nice solution, I implemented a method to automatically spot long weekends. It takes into account also those cases when a holiday falls on a Tuesday or a Thursday, as the OP asked.

The method is available in this project:
https://github.com/kryptonite0/python-long-weekends

```
import holidays as holidays_api
from long_weekends.long_weekends import spot_holiday_bridges

start = '2021-01-01'
end = '2021-12-31'
holidays = holidays_api.CH(prov='TI', years=[2020, 2021, 2022])
bridges, long_weekends = spot_holiday_bridges(
    start=start, end=end, holidays=holidays)
```

```
bridges
[Timestamp('2021-05-14 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00')]


long_weekends
[Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-01-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-03-19 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-03-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-03-21 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-14 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-16 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-22 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-23 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-05 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-06 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-27 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-06-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-10-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00')]
```